# Rails/coffeescript/datatables, after changing views, need to refresh to reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, datatables

I'm sorry for asking this here as I typically find everything I need to ask, but I think my problem is I do not know really WHAT to search for to get the answer.   Here goes.   I am playing with datatables to provide sorted/ajaxified/searchable tables.   Everything loads correctly when I hit the site.   It is fine after I add data to the table or sort or search.

But, if I navigate from the page, say back to the home page, and then back to the page with the table, the table is still there, but the datatables stuff is gone.   I assume this is a matter of me JUST starting to work with JS/Ajax and the like for my Rails app and I probably am just in need of something very simple.

The specific code I'm using is:

```
$ ->
$("#customers").dataTable
sDom: "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
sPaginationType: "bootstrap"
```

If I watch the page load, I think I see the issue.   When it loads initially, or any time I send it back after adding a new customer, I see all the JS and CSS files load.  But, when I hit back, it's a cached call and it's not loading any of those again, so, I'm assuming I'm not "initializing" the JS again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, my problem was really not knowing enough to know exactly what to ask.   The problem here wasn't dataTables or JS or Ajax or any of that.   It was Turbolinks in Rails 4.   Because it caches to make things seem fast, whenever I'd leave the page and come back to it, I'd have to refresh to get the underlying javascript to initialize.

Turbolinks has an option you can pass into your script to make a document ready on page:restore.  That worked.  If anyone else runs into this maybe they'll find this helpful.